# insecure script when running a $.getJSON with jasmine

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, asynchronous, jasmine

I am learning jasmine and right now I'm trying to test a $.getJSON to get a github user's name using the github API. This is the code I am running:

index.html:

```
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <title>Jasmine Tests</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" 
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/2.6.2/jasmine.css">
     </head>
    <body>
    <script
     src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
     integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
     crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
     <script 
    src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/2.6.2/jasmine.js">
     </script>
     <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/2.6.2/jasmine-
     html.js"></script>
     <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/2.6.2/boot.js">
    </script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
     </body>
    </html>
```

test.js:

```
    function getUserInfo(username){
      return $.getJSON('https://api.github.com/users/' + username);
      //remember that all jquery ajax methods return a promise!
   }

describe("#getUserInfo", function(){
          it("returns the correct name for the user", function(done){
            getUserInfo('elie').then(function(data){
              expect(data.name).toBe('Elie Schoppik');
              done(); //invoke to make sure the test does not timeout
            });
      });
});
```

I am running on cloud9 and getting the following error:

Mixed Content: The page at 'https://preview.c9users.io/pvanny1124/web-dev-bootcamp-1/Jasmine/index.html?_c9_id=livepreview12&_c9_host=https://ide.c9.io' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

What can I do? Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 2):

Load all your references over HTTPS.  Change this line to use HTTPS.

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Happy to help. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.